# Unable to install debian hyperv

Tags: debian, hard-drive, hyper-v, installation

I have created VM gen1 at our hyper-v server. When the installation get to disc section, i get error No disc drive was detected. I have vhdx at IDE controller  assigned. What can be a cause?  Installation asks for a driver, which is suitable for hyperv?

Comment: You should be using generation 2 for Debian stable or later (with dynamic memory and secure boot disabled).

Comment: Gen2 VM won't boot from scsi dvd locaion 0 ISO, with secure boot and dynamic ram disabled...

Comment: Which Hyper-V version is it? Is it up to date?

Comment: windows server 2016